# Weird Trouble IOS Iphone App to Application Loader - Mac Flash Pro CS6

Tags: iphone, ios, flash-cs6, application-loader

This is about the 5th time I have deleted all certificates, made new ones, republished, and tried to load. I seem to get the same errors every time. I am sure the provisioning and certificate are for distribution and not development.
It seems only one little section of the adobe help mentions the zipping and unzipping. Is this hackish method really working for people? Is the ipa the only file including in the zipped folder?

When I do this, unzip it, and go into the payload folder I see the file APPNAME.app, but it looks like a piece of paper with a big white circle with a line through it. When I try to click on it the mac says, “can’t open this file”
Is this normal? I zipped it and tried uploading but I am still getting these errors:

Unable to extract codesigning entitlements from your application. Please make sure rufood8 is a valid Mach executable that’s properly codesigned.

Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an Iphone distribution certificate.

Comment: Please. I know it is not impossible. I just revoked all my certificates, redid everything, published fine with the developer certs, and put it on an ipad (through itunes). I then changed the distribution certificates to those that I just made, but same errors. hmmm

Comment: What is the error messege you get?  I delivered my app a few times with hackintosh successfuly. I developed with flash-pro-cs6 on windows! you need to send the packaged .ipa without extract... you need to publish with flash using the newest mobileprovision and p12. and validate that they both distribution and they both belongs to each other! You first create the certificate and then the profile. only then you download both and publish!!